# How can I upload songs into Google Music on Ubuntu?

Tags: google

I'm interested in using [Google Play for Music](https://play.google.com/music/), how can I use it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Music Manager is now (and has been for a while) officially available for Ubuntu (32&64 bit .deb packages as well as Fedora/SUSE).

Download the package which then installs the repository for you from here

- https://play.google.com/music/listen#manager_pl

Answer (score 2):

I've been running it in Ubuntu 11.04 under Wine 1.3 without any problems. It runs the same as my Win 7 box.

To get it running, first I installed Wine 1.3:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.3
```

Originally I copied the exe from my Win 7 box but recently I found you can just download from the [Unofficial MusicManager for Linux](http://code.google.com/p/google-music-manager-linux-wine/downloads/list) GoogleCode page.

After unzipping to the location of your choice, either use 'wine MusicManager.exe' from the terminal or just double click MusicManager.exe in Nautilus to run.

You can find a lot more info in the following [thread on the Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1767374):

Another option you might want to check up on is the [MusicManager Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/obojocfchdgdpgcigcdhdnlakfcbbgfn?hl=en-US). It looks like it used to work at one point, but has since broken.

Comment: response outdated.  Google Music Manager now fully supported on linux: https://play.google.com/music/listen#manager_pl

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-musicmanager.list'

wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install google-musicmanager-beta
```